# Server control checkbox cannot be checked in ASP.NET?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I am trying to create a toggle button in my project when i added a server control checkbox the checkbox cannot be checked,but when i used a html control and that checkbox can be checked, What am i missing

```
<div class="material-switch ">
       <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
       <label for="CheckBox1" class="label-primary" ></label>
    </div>
```

> Css Used

```
.material-switch > input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;   
}

.material-switch > label {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 0px;
    position: relative; 
    width: 40px;  
}

.material-switch > label::before {
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-radius: 8px;
    content: '';
    height: 16px;
    margin-top: -8px;
    position:absolute;
    opacity: 0.3;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    width: 40px;
}
.material-switch > label::after {
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-radius: 16px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    content: '';
    height: 24px;
    left: -4px;
    margin-top: -8px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -4px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    width: 24px;
}
.material-switch > input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before {
    background: inherit;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.material-switch > input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::after {
    background: inherit;
    left: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I got it  !!!!!!! 
I am getting that issue because when the controls are rendered to the webpage the ID of the checkbox changes...it is appended with ctl00_RightPlaceHolder_ because of that the label control was not able to find the control because it is looking for control with this id "CheckBox1"

So i added `ClientIDMode="Static"` to make the ID static

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

change your label for attribute from "someSwitchOptionPrimary" to id of asp:CheckBox. working example is as followed :

```
<div class="material-switch">
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
        <label for="CheckBox1" class="label-primary" ></label>
  </div>
```